# Send WhatsApp Template message with Twilio

Tags: templates, twilio, whatsapp

In their docs, Twilio say that all I need to do in order to send a WhatsApp template message is to simply send the message, and they will recognize that it's a saved template message and use it:

> To send a templated message, include the full body of the message in
> the API call. Twilio will send the message as a templated message if
> it matches one of the approved templates.

However, the example they give is by using their `Client` object (see the example [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates)).

I don't use that object, in my WhatsApp bot I use `MessageResponse` like this:

```
def bot():
    ...
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    msg.body(some_text)
    return str(resp)
```

I tried changing `some_text` to the text that appears in my template message, but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you are sending a message using TwiML in response to an incoming message you don’t need to use a template. As the message is in response to another message you are in the [24 hour conversation window](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api#conversational-messaging-on-whatsapp) and you can send any message.

Comment: Thanks! However the only reason I want to use a template is for the buttons :) I want to have 3 buttons for the user to push, that's why I want to use templates (not for the 24-hour window)

Comment: Sadly the Twilio API for WhatsApp doesn’t currently support interactive messages in conversation messages.

Comment: I see. So if I understand correctly, I cannot use buttons in my WhatsApp bot? Or I can do so by converting the code to use some other Twilio library? (not totally clear on differences between "regular" Twilio to "TwiML" etc.

Comment: You cannot use buttons in your bot during conversational messages. You can only do so when sending a templated message outside of the 24 hour conversation window